# how to virtualhost with podman

Tags: networking, centos, gitlab-ce, podman

my server running gitlab in podman.

I want gitlab connecting of subdomain.

Test command

```
podman start gitlab-ce --VIRTUAL-HOST=test.example.com -p 80
```

how to virtualHost setting in podman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#run-the-image), the container can be started with:

```
sudo podman run --detach \
  --hostname gitlab.example.com \
  --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://test.example.com/';" \
  --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

`sudo` is needed to bind port 80 and 443.

Comment: my server have many service.
I want 80 port not having gitlab.
because my service use 80 port.
example1.test.com connect my service
exalple2.test.com connect my  service 2

Comment: Then you'll need to configure a reverse proxy (for example `traefik`, `haproxy` or `nginx`) in front of your services. This is not a problem that you can solve with the GitLab image.